# Upgrading laptop RAM: format and speed questions

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

As I'm upgrading my laptop’s RAM—a Sony Vaio VPC-EB—and I want to consider some options. Currently my lp uses:
2x2 GB DDR3 1333(667) MHz SO-DIMMs.

Questions:

1. Clock speed - can I buy 1600? Why? What does determine that speed (will I need to mess with the BIOS in order to tweak something if I buy 1600 instead of 1333)?
2. Can I buy only 1 4GB module and have 6GB (2+4). I remember from my earlier days something that this arrangement is not optimal? Can someone explain? What would be the problems caused?
3. As I understand the form factor is determined by the SO-DIMM (small-outline dual in-line memory module)? So if I buy it I can be sure that it will fit?
4. How can I be sure that my motherboard supports 1x4GB modules (I know that some don’t; what determines that)?

Comment: Without providing any manufacturer information there's no way to know what your motherboard can and can't handle.  I use Crucial.com for memory specs for most older model laptops that don't have specs on their websites, otherwise I'd go right to the manufacturer to look up what it can support.

Comment: Sure I'm trying to look it up now, but is there really no way to tell? Maybe this is indicated by some parameter of the motherboard? Or is it really a feature that is independed of anything on the hardware and just either has to be or not to be?

Comment: What make/model of laptop is it?

Comment: sony vaio vpceb

Comment: Your post contains too many separate questions. This is not a good fit for our Q&A format, so please create separate posts for each distinct issue you have. See also: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can user RAM of a higher speed, i.e. 1600 MHz vs 1333 MHz in your case.

For reference:

- 1600 (800 MHz) DDR3 is usually referred to as PC3-12800
- 1333 (667 MHz) DDR3 is usually referred to as PC3-10600

there are also low voltage versions (names PC3L-xxxxx) available, which runs at 1.35V instead of the normal 1.5V, so make sure you get whichever type is right for your system.

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes, you can buy higher rated RAM for your system. It will possibly run at a lower speed if your laptop doesn't support the higher speed memory.
2. Normally a 2+4 GB configuration is fine. Some systems (particularly desktop boards) use "Dual Channel" memory, where you can get better performance when using pairs of memory of the same type and size.
3. The SO-DIMM is as you say the form factor, so you are sure they will fit into the memory slot, but you can not be sure they are compatible with your system (could be too large capacity, or too low clock frequency).
4. To be sure what your laptop supports check with the manufacturer website or on some memory configurator (Both [Kingston](http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/options/) and [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/advisor) have one available on their websites)

Comment: Currently my RAM modules are 1.5V, but crucial.com offers me 1.35V with guaranteed compatibility - can this be correct? Also, I have found my memory controler to work in dual channel mode: Dual Channel  (128-bit) --> North Bridge: Intel Arrandale IMC - so I should buy 2x4GB then I guess.